# Unless condition in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, handlebars.js

In Handlebars we can write condition like #unless eg.

```
<input type="checkbox" {{#unless fee.isSubmitted}}disabled{{/unless}}>
```

How can we write this logic using angular js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular, we have particular `ng-something` for each attribute/event you want to add.

So, utilizing `ng-disabled`,

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="!fee.isSubmitted">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-disabled for this

it goes like

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="fee.isSubmitted">
```

the checkbox is disabled unless fee.isSubmitted is true.

Answer (score 2):

there is a directive like ng-disabled (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) which takes an expression. If the expression is true, the disabled flag will be added to the input element. The expression addresses a variable which is on scope like as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="!$ctrl.fee.isSubmitted">
```